# Регулярное выражение java

Tags: регулярные-выражения, java, строки

Добрый день.

Есть строка

```
  1.|-- 14.8.7.134         1.0%     8    2.6  17.4   5.2 141.3  30.6
```

Пытаюсь написать регулярку чтоб вырезало все кроме цифр и точек.
Пришел к такому варианту:

```
 String [] strings = stringFromFile.split("\\s+|-|%|\\|");
```

Но вот проблема - в итоговом массиве присутствуют пустые ячейки

```
"" "1." "" "" "" "14.8.7.134" "1.0" "" "8" "2.6" "17.4" "5.2" "141.3" "30.6"
```

Подскажите, как избавиться от этих пустышек.

Спасибо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String [] strings = stringFromFile.trim().split("[^\\d\\.]+");
```

Comment: В поддержку рабочий пример:  
http://ideone.com/KXUfI7